# React - Reduce Apex Chart Tool tip item distances

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

I want to decrease the distance between the y-axis items on the tooltip, I am using apex charts. The only way I have found so far is to custom code the tooltip but if there is a way provided by Apex charts that I still know about I would like to use that. Please see the image below for context.
I would like to reduce the distance between Total Revenue, Net Income, and Free Cashflow. Here are the options I have set for this chart.

```
const options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'area',
            width: '100%',
            foreColor: graphVar.color,
            toolbar: {
                show: false,
            },
        },
        grid: {
            show: graphVar.grid
        },
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        },
        stroke: {
            width: 3,
            curve: 'smooth'
        },
        xaxis: {
            color: graphVar.color,
            type: 'datetime',
        },
        yaxis: {
            labels: {
                formatter: function (val) {
                    return val
                }
            }
        },
        fill: {
            opacity: 0.5
        },
        tooltip: {
            x: {
                format: 'MMM dd yyyy'
            },
            y: {
                formatter: function (value, {series, seriesIndex, dataPointIndex, w}) {
                    return value.toFixed(2)
                },  
            },
            fillSeriesColor: false,
            fixed: {
                enabled: false,
                position: 'topRight'
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can customize everything through css. For the tooltip series height you can use:

```css
.apexcharts-tooltip-series-group {
    max-height: 10px;
}
```

Unfortunately, I don't know of a reference to css classes; I typically use "Inspect" to see what is what and occasionally the source code.